# Non-modal QWidget dialog that stays on top of the window

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want a dialog which stays on top of my main window and not other windows. I derived a class and added some flags. If I call the dialog now with `show()` the dialog appears and is staying on top as long as I don't press a button or whatever. Then the dialog goes to background again.

```
Dial::Dial(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) 
{
  this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::Dialog);
  // ...
```

Consequently, I looked into the docu and found this:

> Indicates that the widget is a tool window. A tool window is often a
>   small window with a smaller than usual title bar and decoration,
>   typically used for collections of tool buttons. If there is a parent,
>   the tool window will always be kept on top of it.

Happily, I added this line into my singleton creating the dialog.

```
d->mainWindow = new Foo();
d->dial->setParent(d->mainWindow);
```

Now the dialog is just embedded into my central widget (`QOpenGlWidget`) and is not a dialog anymore. Somehow, I seem to lack understanding what the docu is telling me? How can I get the dialog stay on top of my application and what does the docu mean?

[image]

Comment: why are you using a `QWidget` instead of `QDialog`?

Comment: QDialog behaves basically the same. I just tested.

Comment: There is no platform independent way to do this. I spent *a lot* of time at my last job trying to find a solution to this problem.
You can achieve this effect on windows with some combination of windowflags and similar, but not the right effect on mac with some *different* combination of windowflags. The behavior on mac also is OS version dependent. If you are fine with the popup disappearing when the application loses focus and reappearing when it gains focus, windowflags can work.

Comment: A pity, I already expected there is no "clean" fix for that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem. The following code will generate a `QWidget` that will allways stay on top of the `QMainWindow`:

```
#include "QApplication"
#include "QMainWindow"
#include "QLineEdit"
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow w;
    w.show ();

    QWidget *pLineEdit = new QWidget(&w);
    pLineEdit->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::Dialog);
    pLineEdit->show ();

    a.exec ();
}
```

*Tested with Qt 5.9.*

Comment: Well it stays in front. As long as I don't use it. After pressing a button on the dialog AND then going to the main window, it directly goes behind all windows. At least on Windows. Was not testing in Linux.

Comment: Dude! You saved the job today. Thanks for the hint. It totally works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've already solved this by now but you can try the WindowStaysOnTopHint flag when you construct the dialog:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = this->windowFlags();
flags |= Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint;
this->setWindowFlags(flags);
```

Then use show() instead of exec() to make it non-modal:

```
dlg->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the modality ([documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop)) of the widget, like this:

```
QWidget *dialog = new QWidget(window, Qt::Dialog);
dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
dialog->show();
```

However, I'd recommend to use the pre-configured [`QDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) class, which handles all that stuff for you:

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(window);
dialog->exec();
```

Comment: If I use this, the dialog blocks all input events from the main-window. Is there a chance that the system is just somehow bugged in Qt, because it just seems to be non-working for non-modal dialogs?

Comment: No, that's just the way it works. I just run that code with a very simple window, everytime I move my mouse in the window itself it is moved to the dialog, however I can put other windows on top

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this for non-modal dialogs?

Comment: I just went through the documentation, all window flags and the source code of [qdialog](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.cpp), however apart from modality I couldn't find anything that makes the window stay on top of just one other window

Answer (score 1):

Use **QDialog** instead of **QWidget**, and **pass the parent widget** in its constructor function.

```
QDialog* pDlg = new QDialog(this);
pDlg->show();
```